# How to define dependency in sbt build so IDEA shows it under External Libraries?

Tags: intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new to Scala and IntelliJ IDEA. I have installed both the `Scala` and `SBT` plugins in IntelliJ IDEA. I'm trying to declare a test dependency to ScalaTest in `build.sbt`.

I have tried to add the following library dependency in `build.sbt`: `org.scalatest:scalatest_2.11:4.1.0` and my `build.sbt` looks as follows:

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.11" % "4.1.0" % "test"
```

The problem is that ScalaTest doesn't show up in IDEA. The only external libraries I currently have are `SBT: org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.4:jar` and `SBT: sbt-and-plugins`.

Comment: Do you have `Enable auto-import` enabled.

Comment: Did you check the version number of ScalaTest? The most recent version I see `2.2.1`.

Comment: @nash_ag I've gone to `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Build Tools, SBT` and clicked `auto-import`. @user3567830 nope didn't check that but I've changed `libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" % "scalatest_2.10" % "2.1.0" % "test"`. Seems like it's working. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Use `"2.2.3"` in the dependency for the version part.

`build.sbt` should look as follows:

```
name := "untitled"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.3" % "test"
```

Note the additional `%` sign between the 1st and the 2nd parts of the dependency and the missing `_2.11` in the 2nd part (it's implied from the `scalaVersion` due to `%%`).

**#protip** You should be using [sbt-updates](https://github.com/rtimush/sbt-updates) more often as it'd tell you about the latest version after executing `dependencyUpdates`. That's how I was told about the version of ScalaTest when the home page says 2.2.1 is the latest. I can highly recommend the tool while working with sbt.

Comment: Hi Jacek, thank you for the help and the protip. Isn't there a way to automatically download plugin and library updates via IntelliJ IDEA? Also, I found it quite helpful to go to `File > Invalidate Caches/Restart` as my system wasn't downloading anything even after inserting those lines.